# Unity: How to use Generics in ScriptableObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a Scriptable object that looks like this:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "PlayerPrefsDefault", menuName = "Base/PlayerPrefsDefault", order = 1)]
public class PlayerPrefsDefaults : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<PlayerPrefsDefaultInt> playerPrefsDefaultInts = new List<PlayerPrefsDefaultInt>();

    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerPrefsDefault<DataType>
    {
        public string key;
        public DataType value;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerPrefsDefaultInt : PlayerPrefsDefault<int> { }
}
```

It works so far. However, this is not the kind of aesthetics that my heart is yearning for. 
 
So, **step 1**, why can't I or rather how could I have this in my ScriptableObject (exposed to the inspector, of course):

```
    public List<PlayerPrefsDefault<int>> playerPrefsDefaultInts;
```

Naturally, this implies the use of multiple lists, one for each data type. 
 
Consequently, **step 2**, I would actually prefer to define:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerPrefsDefault
    {
        public System.Type type;
        public string key;
        public object value;
    }
```

I would like to have the possibility to assign arbitrary values (int, float, bool, string, UnityEngine.Vector3, etc.) to the value variable (and adapt the inspector GUI to the choice made with type, I know how to do that)

Eventually, generally speaking: how can I be as generic as possible with ScriptableObjects?

Comment: It is not possible since Generics like `PlayerPrefsDefault<T>` are not serializable. Also your second attempt `System.Type` and `object` are also not serializable.